# How would you assign n number of points from one series to same number of points in another series based on L2 or some specified distance function?

Tags: algorithm, simulated-annealing

The problem I am working on requires me to assign a fixed number of points from one series to the same number of points from another series. Think of it as assigning predicted values to corresponding experimental values. For this case, assume each point belongs to R^2, and we are only concerned about the average Euclidean distance between the resultant matchings.

One way to do this is to greedily assign the points with the least possible distance, which does give one of the lowest average distance, but we cannot be sure if it's the absolute best. Besides, points left to be assigned at the end end up being connected to really far points as no close alternatives are left.

Another method to do this is via simulated annealing or similar methods that find the global minimum, but on a sample set of 100 points generated randomly, this performs significantly worse than the greedy approach.

For some more context on the problem: I am trying to create an NMR assignment algorithm that predicts chemical shift values for a given structure and assigns them to experimental values obtained. I am working with a 1H-15N HSQC plot which is just a 2D graph of points. I would also like to hear if someone has come across a similar problem that was solved using machine learning techniques. As far as I see it, ML is good for classification and regression but not really for such assignment type problems.

Comment: You already saw that ML is not suited and still ask for ML (and tag the question ML)? Strange. Well... to me, this is exactly the [linear-assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem). Precompute the pairwise distancematrix between those sets, setup the assignment problem and be happy about a global-opt in (~) cubic time.

Comment: I just meant I haven't seen ML used in such a way but if anyone has, I just want to know. Removed the tag.

Comment: Sounds like the minimum weight bipartite matching problem: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)#Maximum-weight_matching